# rails 3 - Help Returning a nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Hello I have the following in my Create Controller:

```
  def create
    @requestable = find_requestable

    if !@requestable.nil?
     . ..
```

And then:

```
  def find_requestable  
    params.each do |name, value|  
      if name =~ /(.+)_id$/  
        return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)  
      end
    end  
    nil  
  end
```

this works find when find_requestable sends back a paratemter, but if it doesn't it's not sending back a NIL which causes everything to error with:

```
NameError (uninitialized constant Undefined):
  app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:133:in `find_requestable'
  app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:131:in `each'
  app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:131:in `find_requestable'
  app/controllers/request_threads_controller.rb:52:in `create'
  app/middleware/flash_session_cookie_middleware.rb:14:in `call'
```

Why isn't find_requestable sending back nil? thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Third line of your `find_requestable` method, first check to see if `name` is `blank`. Give that a shot.

```
if !name.blank? && name =~ /(.+)_id$/
```

---

UPDATE: Answer in Comment:

The only other thing I can think of is that one of your params has `Undefined` as its value, which is causing `return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)` to throw up. Can you take a look at the HTTP Headers and the POST parameters that are being sent across the wire?

Comment: In your method, which line is 133?

Comment: return $1.classify.constantize.find(value)

Comment: Maybe we can do something during the loop (params.each do |name, value|), keep an index and if it's on the last index of params add an else that says return nil --- thoughts?

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is that one of your params has `Undefined` as its value. Can you take a look at the HTTP Headers and the POST parameters that being sent across the wire? Sorry I can't be of any more help.

Comment: Ya I do! (undefined_id:undefined), the find_requestable can't account for that?

Comment: I don't think that'll work because `params` is a hash, not an array. Given that, the order in which its values are accessed is undetermined/random. So counting and checking for the last index may not help at all, as the `Undefined` value could pop up unexpectedly.

Comment: It doesn't seem like it, unfortunately. =(

Comment: What you could do is pre-process the params object and remove any entries with an `Undefined` value.

Comment: No problem! Glad I could help. I'll update my answer to include the things I've said in the comments.